# Upgrade ibm_watson in conda

Tags: conda, upgrade

I have used the following to install ibm_watson package:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ibm-watson
```

This installs ibm_watson 4.7.0 However, I need ibm_watson 5.2.3. How do I upgrade in conda? There is nothing that I found.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the syntax to specify a version when `conda install`-ing is to do

```
 conda install <package-name>=<version>
```

very much like `pip install` calls.

However, in this specific case, you can check on the [anaconda.org website](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ibm-watson) that 4.7 is currently the latest version for which a conda package is available.

If you really need a different version, I would recommend to use a different installation method. Make sure to uninstall the conda installed version though:

1. `conda uninstall ibm-watson`
2. `pip install "ibm-watson>=5.2.3"`

Comment: Not sure how you are saying anything else than what I said.

Answer (score -1):

I figured that we need to add pip to conda environment:

```
conda install pip
```

Then you can upgrade as suggested by Github:

```
pip install --upgrade "ibm-watson>=5.2.3"
```

I was under the impression that once you have conda, everything needs to go through conda alone, not pip. Hopefully, someone will find this helpful one day.

Comment: You are mistaken that everything needs to go through conda. What should be avoided at all though is to `pip install --upgrade` a package that you have previously installed through `conda`

Comment: I believe, my answer admitted to the mistake when I said "I was under the impression....". After trying hard to upgrade through conda, I figured what my mistake was. That downvote was uncalled for.